# What is a Policy for controlling access in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In the Kubernetes documentation for controlling-access to the API server, under the [Authorization section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/controlling-access/#authorization) it says that authorization is controlled through a Policy.

However, a Policy is not found as an API resource:

```
❯ k api-resources | grep -i policy
networkpolicies                   netpol              networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         NetworkPolicy
poddisruptionbudgets              pdb                 policy/v1                              true         PodDisruptionBudget

❯ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.25.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.25.3+k3s1
```

So what exactly is a Policy?  How is it setup?

The docs are not very clear on this point.

Comment: I believe that the API Sever need to authorize with one of the ways `Node`, `RBAC`, `ABAC` etc... And I think Policy comes from ABAC. Not sure why k8s document doesn't have the details what you mentioned. If you use `RBAC`, I think it is enough to authorize requests to the API server.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...under the Authorization section it says that authorization is controlled through a Policy.

The sample you saw is a cluster that uses ABAC. From your screenshot your cluster is likely to use RBAC which access policy is not used.

> So what exactly is a Policy? How is it setup?

Here's the official documentation for [Attribute-based access control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/abac/)